# ms sql server datasource java config in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, datasource, spring-java-config, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to use java config for my ms sql server, but unable to find any information regarding how to define it as Bean in config class.
I have used Oracle earlier and it was very easy to configure it. I used to write this code for Oracle.

```
@Bean
DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {

    OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
    dataSource.setUser(username);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    dataSource.setURL(url);
    dataSource.setImplicitCachingEnabled(true);
    dataSource.setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(true);
    return dataSource;
}
```

As of now I am using `application.properties` but I don't wants to continue using this file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the dedicated [SQLServerDataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/reference/sqlserverdatasource-class?view=ssdt-18vs2017) like you did with Oracle:

```
@Bean
DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {

    SQLServerDataSource dataSource = new SQLServerDataSource();
    dataSource.setUser(username);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    dataSource.setURL(url);
    return dataSource;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have solved this with BasicDataSource suggested by pvpkiran

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
@Bean
DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {

    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setUser(username);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    dataSource.setURL(url);
    .........
    .........
    return dataSource;
}
```

Ms Sql is a Relational db. So BasicDataSource should suffice.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to define a `DataSource` bean as Spring Boot uses auto-configuration to create one based on `spring.datasource` properties. You can use `application.yml` to define them:

```
spring:
  datasource:
     url: jdbc:sqlserver://myserver
     username: myuser
     password: mypassword
```

If you are using `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` JDBC driver class it will get picked up by default. Otherwise you need to specify `spring.datasource.driver-class-name` property. Do note that as of Spring Boot 2 [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) is the default pool implementation.

Refer to the [Microsoft JDBC docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=ssdt-18vs2017) and [Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html) for further reading.

Comment: Thanks for the details Karol, but as I mentioned I am using the same approach now, but I wants to use java config so that I can use PCF CUP service to get datasource details.